# how to take a screen shot from a mapview

Tags: iphone

In my application i have used mapview. On particular place i can put annotation. i want to take the snap shot of that place with annotation in it.

i tried to implement this.

```
CGSize size = self.view.bounds.size;
CGRect screensize = CGRectMake(40,40,size.width-240,size.height-400);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screensize.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *screenshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshotImage, nil, nil, nil);

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

this code takes the snap but it takes the snap from (0,0) coordinates. i want to take the snap from (40,40) coordinates and the size of the image should be 80*80.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it directly. Get the entire image and the crop the desired region.

```
CGSize size = self.view.bounds.size;
CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(40, 40, 80, 80);

/* Get the entire on screen map as Image */
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage * mapImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

/* Crop the desired region */
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(mapImage.CGImage, cropRect);
UIImage * cropImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]; 
CGImageRelease(imageRef);

/* Save the cropped image */
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(cropImage, nil, nil, nil);

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```