# iPhone Map Screenshot without Switching Views

Tags: iphone, mapkit, screenshot

I'm working on an app in which I am looking to take a screenshot of the map to record where a person was when the action was performed, which is then sent in a report back to the server. I do not want the person to see the map pop up while the screenshot is being taken and the user should be oblivious of the screenshot until they review the report.

I have looked at the following question:
[how to take a screen shot from a mapview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517268/how-to-take-a-screen-shot-from-a-mapview)

But they are making the map visible in order to take the screenshot.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why don't you just record the actual location?

Comment: do you need the actual image?

Comment: @jtbandes: I can (and am) recording the person's location, but I want to make it so that when a user visits the report, they can have a sense of context of where the report was made to, and I would like to avoid making the server make the map (since the report is supposed to be compatable with several different service types and they all may not have access to map rendering tools, but do have access to image display tools).

Comment: @TommyG: Yes, since I can't gurantee the service used to store/display the report can render a map based on the user's location. The data can be historical (referenced several years after the initial report was made), so if the area changes (new roads or buildings have been constructed), a map rendered at the moment will not contain the historical data and have a different context.

Answer (score 0):

If understand correctly, you have a view somewhere and you do not want it on screen, but you want to capture an image of it.

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(mapView.bounds.size,mapView.alpha, mapView.contentScaleFactor);
            CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
            mapView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            [mapView.layer renderInContext:context];
            UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. The code, as is, produces an image of the size 0 bytes. Modifying it to include:

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

Instead produces a blank image of the screen's size.